# Captuvo iPod barcode scanner shows incompatible firmware after sleep

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I am attempting to implement a small iPod application using the Captuvo barcode scanning sled, using Captuvo SDK 22 and iOS 7. The application receives a barcode and sends it to a webview.

The application sort of works. I am able to connect to the device and scan a barcode.

However, after the application sleeps (goes to the background), on the next wakeup, the scanner fails with an error, saying "Incompatible Firmware".

Oddly, I can exit the application, start it again, and the device will connect without an error.

The closest I have come so far has been to try restarting the scanner when the application is foregrounded by implementing:

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

It's maddeningly close to working. This is my first attempt at iOS development, so maybe I am missing something fundamental about the application lifecycle. Outside of the official SDK, there is relatively little documentation on how to program the Captuvo, so I'd be interested in any suggestions.

Here is the complete code:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Captuvo.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *barcode;    
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *strURL = @"http://myurl.com/scan.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleForeground)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)handleForeground {
    [self.webView reload];
    [self initCaptuvoSDK];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)initCaptuvoSDK
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] removeCaptuvoDelegate:self];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] addCaptuvoDelegate:self];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] stopDecoderHardware];
    ProtocolConnectionStatus connectionStatus = [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];

    NSString *message;
    switch (connectionStatus) {
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusConnected:
            message = @"Connected!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusAlreadyConnected:
            message = @"Already Connected!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusBatteryDepleted:
            message = @"Battery depleted!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnect:
            message = @"Error connecting!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnectIncompatiableSledFirmware:
            message = @"Incompatible firmware!";
            break;
        default:
            message = @"Other!";
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:message
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)decoderReady
{
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] enableDecoderBeeperForGoodRead:YES persistSetting:NO] ;
        [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]setDecoderSerialTriggerTimeoutInMilliSeconds:5000 persistSetting:NO];
    });
}

- (void)decoderDataReceived:(NSString *)data
{
    NSLog(@"decoderDataReceived");
    if(data != nil) {
        // send barcode to the webview
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"processBarcode('%@');", data];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem similar to you. I modified the method in `AppDelegate.m` file like below. It worked for me.

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] stopDecoderHardware];
}
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];
}
```